# SQlite - Substr

Tags: sql, sqlite, substr

In Sqlite, I have a column with dates that comes as follows: Hours (VARCHAR) Friday|18:00-2:00

in my code I have the following, my idea is to extract the text from |, since it would give me a range of hours:

```
select count(distinct b.id), h.business_id, substr(h.hours, '|')
    , b.stars
```

However, I still have the same result substr(h.hours, '|') Friday |  18:00-2:00

I need you to just extract from the above: 18:00-2:00

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.id),
    h.business_id,
    TRIM(SUBSTR(h.hours, INSTR(h.hours, '|') + 1)) AS extracted_hours,
    b.stars
FROM
    first_table_name AS h
JOIN
    second_table_name AS b ON h.business_id = b.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Navkar, this is an test enviroment of Coursera, and gives me an error of "no such function: INSTR"

Comment: @edward_apc No `instr()` function? Sure you're using SQLite?

Comment: I'm not sure about Coursera environment. Maybe you can create a SQLite database locally. It's really easy and simple to do so. I can suggest you to use DBeaver, its a great database administration tool where you can visualize the table, create and run the queries and much more.